# Pick values of given properties from object into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have an object:

```
person = { 
    birth_year: 1970, 
    first_name: "John", 
    last_name: "Doe", 
    occupation: "Doctor", 
    city: "Boston",
    married: true 
}
```

I have an array of key names in given order:

```
keys = ["occupation", "last_name", "city"]
```

I want to get this array:

```
["Doctor", "Doe", "Boston"]
```

It is important, that the answer should guarantee the order (JavaScript does not guarantee the order for object iteration).

I think there is probably some utility function in lodash/underscore to do it simply, but can't figure out any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for this. Map loops through an array and creates a new array by applying a function to each item. When you use the `keys` array as a starting point, and return the value in `o` for that key, you'll get a new array with only values.

When using "dynamic" key names, you use a `object[stringKeyName]` notation to retrieve a value.

```js
var o = { 
    birth_year: 1970, 
    first_name: "John", 
    last_name: "Doe", 
    occupation: "Doctor", 
    city: "Boston",
    married: true 
};

var keys = ["occupation", "last_name", "city"];

var result = keys.map(function(k) { return o[k]; });

console.log(result);
```

If it fits your style, you can create a helper method to replace the anonymous function:

```js
var o = { birth_year: 1970, first_name: "John", last_name: "Doe", occupation: "Doctor", city: "Boston", married: true };
var keys = ["occupation", "last_name", "city"];

var prop = obj => key => obj[key];
var result = keys.map(prop(o));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: We could even simplify this into `var result = keys.map(k => o[k])`, but I still don't like it.

Comment: If it's a matter of style, you could wrap some stuff in a helper. Have a look at the second snippet.

Comment: If the order matters, this or the `_.map` function is the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

With `Lodash` you could use `pick` and `values`

```js
var o = {
  birth_year: 1970,
  first_name: "John",
  last_name: "Doe",
  occupation: "Doctor",
  city: "Boston",
  married: true
}
var keys = ["occupation", "last_name", "city"];

var result = _.values(_.pick(o, keys));
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.15.0/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Does it guarantee the order?

Comment: @Mikhail Batcer I am not sure about that.

Comment: @NenadVracar That's the reason I asked this "nooby" question... :))

Comment: `pick` creates an object, `values` loops through an object's keys. Object keys are not sorted by spec (http://stackoverflow.com/a/5525820/3297291), so you can't expect `result` to follow the order of `keys` in this example.

Answer (score 0):

For those who stumble on this answer years later. You can use lodash [at](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#at) method

```
// I have an object:
const person = { 
    birth_year: 1970, 
    first_name: "John", 
    last_name: "Doe", 
    occupation: "Doctor", 
    city: "Boston",
    married: true 
}

// I have an array of key names in given order:
const keys = ["occupation", "last_name", "city"]

// I want to get this array:
// ["Doctor", "Doe", "Boston"]
const result = at(person, ["occupation", "last_name", "city"])
```